# Copy and .# in file name

Tags: groovy, gradle

I faced with one gradle issue (or may be groovy related)

When I trying to copy file with .# in its name nothing is happened.
Example:

```
task c(type: Copy) {
  from (".#webclasspath#")
  into "destdir"
}
```

Please, could you provide way how to process such files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems that there is a bug in gradle, ant works just fine

```
task c_ant << {
  ant.copy(file : '.#webclasspath#', todir : 'destdir')
}
```